# What happens to yeast in bread after it dies?

Tags: baking

I have been told by someone that afterm the yeast dies in bread when you bake it, it "disappears". Is this true? I always thought I could taste yeast in really good bread but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing truly disappears even in thermonuclear reactions and baking bread is not even close to that.

When you bake bread, water evaporates into the atmosphere and the CO<sub>2</sub> and other volatiles released by the yeast bacteria dissipate there as well, which means that the solids of the yeast just remain inside the bread.

So you can tell your friend that their statement is untrue. <s>and that with each bite of bread they're eating a graveyard full of dead yeast bodies...</s>  **;-)**

Comment: It is an irrational mind which would enjoy bread until learning there were dead yeast in it.

Comment: @Sobachatina Absolutely correct: I still enjoy yeast urine (C2H5OH) and bird embryos too...  **;-)**